# Can't get HTML ANCHOR + How to override .onclick of anchor

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my index.html i have 2 anchors. I want to customize their behaviour for the first click on them and after that, change their behaviour for when another click occurs.

```js
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; ++i)
  alert(anchors[i]);
```

```html
<section>
  <a href='pag1'>anchor 1</a>
</section>

<section id='2'>
  <a href='pag2'>anchor 2</a>
</section>
```

But when I do this, the alert that i get is the complete path of the href : C:\Users...\html\pag1;
Why doesn't it return a HTML Anchor Object?

If i do the same but with `<p></p>` it works. It returns a Paragraph Object.

I'm using Chrome as browser ( maybe it has something to do with this? )

I continued to change the  anchors[i].onclick to a function, but it seems that when I click on the anchor the function starts and after it, the anchors still sends me to the href page? How to override this behaviour?

Later Edit:

It was explained to me that this behaviour is caused by the .toString() of the anchor type object.

The questions still remains, how do I force the anchor so that it doesn't send me to another page.

Comment: you need to use preventDefault to avoid the default click behavior

Comment: _"But when i do this, the alert that i get is the complete path of the href"_ That's just the way how `.toString()` works for [HTMLAnchorElements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement#Methods) -> [`HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/toString)

Comment: Ah,interesting. So the .toString() for anchors is ment to do this. Still, the question remains. How do i forcibly stop the href from sending me to another page?

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; ++i) anchors[i].onclick=function(e) { e.preventDefault() }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is when you call the alert function of Javascript. It will turn the argument you passed to string by using `toString()` function.

The `toString()` function is implemented to turn the anchor object to its `href` property.

---

To prevent the behavior of the anchor:

```js
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; ++i){
  anchors[i].onclick = function(){
    // Put your code here.

    return false;
  };
}
```

```html
<section>
  <a href='pag1'>anchor 1</a>
</section>

<section id='2'>
  <a href='pag2'>anchor 2</a>
</section>
```

Comment: forEach does not work over a nodelist in all browsers - try console logging `this`

Comment: @mplungjan Oh I see. Thank you for pointing that out, I edited.

Answer (score 1):

Use `addEventListener()` to prevent the default behavior of `click` on `a` by `e.preventDefault()`. 
Try the following:

```js
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');

anchors.forEach(function(a){
    console.log(a);
    a.addEventListener("click",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<section>
    <a href='pag1'>anchor 1</a>
</section>

<section id='2'>
    <a href='pag2'>anchor 2</a>
</section>
```

Comment: forEach does not work over a nodelist in all browsers